# emacs message: timed out waiting for property-notify event

Tags: emacs, selection, vnc-viewer

```
Mark set
Timed out waiting for property-notify event [3 times]
```

When selecting a large region of code on gnu-emacs like the one shown below I got most of the time the error message above and the command prefix is not recorded (Ctrl-X) so the associated command fails.
Cursor moves becomes very slow. Cancelling the selected region revert cursor moves back to normal.

Note: This is observed through a Real VNC session, no idea if this is related with X or not.
Any idea or workaround ? Thanks.

> GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30)  of
> 2020-04-03 on x86-01.bsys.centos.org

Code region: 2048 lines of this:

```
   parameter [RAM_DEPTH-1:0] ValueLoad = {
128'h11110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001100101011011010,
128'h00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
128'h00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
128'h00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
128'h00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
128'h00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
128'h00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
128'h00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
....
128'h00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
128'h00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
128'h00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
128'h01010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 };
```

Comment: Upgrading to a newer version may or may not help -- 24.3 is fairly old now (~8 years).  28.2 is the most recent release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the: https://gnu.emacs.bug.narkive.com/9ydqOFiF/bug-13486-24-2-92-large-x-selections-timed-out-waiting-for-property-notify-event

You could add the following line to your emacs init file (`.emacs`):

```
(setq select-active-regions (quote only))
```